# Posts of the serial votes

Tags: discussion, support, serial-voting

I got SO MANY SERIAL VOTES that I don't know who did it and where, is there any way to find out which posts are these votes? I know all votes are anonymous, so it's not possible to find who, but all these entries links to the reputation tab, not the actual posts they should be.

Also, this looks extremely unusual to me, can anyone explain why this(serial voting, not the reversal) is happening to me? what does this indicates?

[image: TOO MANY SERIAL VOTES]

Comment: Looks like somebody went through your profile upvoting a bunch of your posts, and it was reverse.

Comment: It is pretty obvious who did this, he accepted your answer at the same time he upvoted your posts.  Too much Berkeley love :)  I posted a comment with a link to this meta question so he can see that it did not turn out well.

Comment: @HansPassant How did you find the post?

Comment: Is there a page to see the track of serial votes?

Answer (score 7):

> Also, this looks extremely unusual to me, can anyone explain why
>   this(serial voting, not the reversal) is happening to me? what does
>   this indicates?

Its not "extremely unusual" :). On SO we have processes in place to ensure that people vote for posts rather than the person who posted them. In your case it was found that someone had "incorrectly" upvoted you in a given time frame and hence those votes were invalidated.

You might want to look at [serial-voting-reversed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)