# More votes reversed than in the serial votes

Tags: discussion, support

This is part of [Posts of the serial votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322148/posts-of-the-serial-votes), according to the comment [Posts of the serial votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322148/posts-of-the-serial-votes#comment339328_322148), the user did serial votes after he accepted one of my answer, but now the votes on the accepted answer was reversed too. That's not right. The serial votes are those that only based on person, the accepted answer is just a normal post that solved the user's question, it is not based on person, it is rather based on the content of the post.

Comment: This may be a rare case in which the script *might* have rolled back more than it needed to, which in all honestly I've not heard of in the last four or so years on Stack Overflow happening before - I believe that the script is more conservative than anything else.  The problem here is that there's no concrete evidence to suggest that the votes placed on *your* answer weren't also illegitimate.

Comment: @Makoto Is there any way to correct this?

Comment: I'm not sure it *can* be corrected since, like I said before, there's not much evidence to suggest that the votes that impacted you weren't illegitimate.

Comment: There is the content of question and answer, and the accepting, isn't that enough?

Comment: No.  Regardless of where the vote was cast, if it was illegitimate, it should be reversed.  You seem to presume that the vote was legitimate whereas there's no evidence to suggest that.

Comment: So you are suggesting any 2+ votes for the same person in a roll should be reversed?

Comment: Again, ***if the votes were illegitimate.*** I'm not sure I wish to continue this argument since there's really no evidence to substantiate that the votes were legitimate at all.  If you can come back with that evidence then perhaps it'd be worth a moderator looking into.

Comment: I don't understand why you keep calling it "illegitimate", and why am I supposed to provide the evidence, I don't EVEN have the meta data on who did the vote, it's you should provide the evidence that it is "illegitimate", not me to prove it's "legitimate"...

Comment: It's more exciting to know how SO works than gain a bunch of reputations. :) if I had the source of the votes fraud detection I ain't ask nothing here! 

Comment: @fluter nobody knows the source of the votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've looked at this, and no more votes were invalidated than those cast in two bursts by this user for your posts. No accept votes were removed, and no votes by anyone else were impacted. The only votes that were removed were normal upvotes cast by this person in two rapid-fire groupings.

I don't see anything that needs correcting here. You still have the accept vote for your answer (and the reputation that went with that), and they can still provide a single upvote for it to replace the one that was removed, if they so desire. They've been cautioned not to shotgun upvotes for many of your answers at once, but that's it.

Comment: I don't have problem on the reputation changes, as you also pointed `they can still provide a single upvote ..., if they so desire`, are they even notified for such event? Anyway, my point is, user find the post being useful and approve and accept the post, user then did `x` upvote to approve this person, that's `1+x` approves, but the `1` being normal according to SO's rules, and `x` being serial votes. Now the system judged all `1+x` votes being offensive.

Comment: @fluter how do you know that 1 is normal? Was it not part of the two groups of votes?

Comment: @Tim I don't know, that's just common sense.

Comment: @fluter So what you are saying is you want to keep one of the serial upvotes? That's not how the system works...

Comment: @Tim I see, Ok. I was just curious about how the judge system works, and only find the formula is secret. :p