# Bounty policies?

Tags: support, downvotes, bounty, etiquette, serial-voting

There is no logic in you serially downvoting something that you keep and want to keep. I understand it is not acceptable to serial vote a specific user. Which you do with this serial downvoting. But it wasn't explicitly said when I read about it in 2012 that BalusC got serial voted but there was no info that it was a breach.

Now I wonder if it is a breach to reward bounties to some user who really helped you or if that is different from voting more or less?

Will you take action against me if I reward a user with many bounties? Will you mean that serial bounties also are a policy breach?

Comment: You should vote for quality of a post, rather than for a specific user.

Comment: Bounties are intended to reward or attract quality posts. If it can be seen that you're using them for another purpose (for example, to funnel reputation to a particular user) they may be invalidated and appropriate action taken.

Comment: I remember telling you that awarding bounties to people rather than posts is a policy breach :)

Comment: You [already know this does not work](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322148/posts-of-the-serial-votes#comment339328_322148).  Rather odd that you ask about it again, what is the point??

Comment: Is there a point you're going to come to at some point across all your meta posts regarding reputation that isn't already covered by meta, the community input and a discussion with a moderator? I apologise, but at the moment I'm failing to see what you're really actually asking/after.

Comment: @JonClements Maybe OP needs to find the most effective ways to push their sock puppets up ;-) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ if so - that won't end well :p

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - *Maybe OP needs to find the most effective ways to push their sock puppets up* -  To be honest, That's not true :)

Comment: @TheLostMind I was joking a bit (see the emo). But it's actually interesting seeing this OP to ask so many (mostly badly achieved) rep related questions recently. Well, I'm going to get some popcorn :-P ...

Comment: So what's the point of even displaying who answered? So that you can serial downvote someone and you refer to regulations that are hidden deep under help pages that are difficult to find. You had every chance to display a very clear message: "This question looks like a duplicate of this other question. Are you sure you want to ask a duplicate question?" I can only assume that you want duplicate question and there is no logic in downvoting something that you keep and want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

A bounty is meant to draw more attention to a question that didn't receive an appropriate answer, not to give a bonus for a particular user you like.

> Will you mean that serial bounties also are a policy breach?

As @TZHX mentioned in their [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322614/bounty-policies#comment341789_322614): If such behavior is detected these bounties might be invalidated by a moderator.

Comment: "Reward existing answer" is an option, that is valid and often used.

Comment: @TZHX But not multiple times targeting a specific user, and not really the intend what a bounty is for IMO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ True, but that's not what you said in your answer.  You said, "A bounty is [...] not to give a bonus to someone who already had written an answer." which is false.

Comment: @Servy Well, the wording was chosen badly, you're right.

Comment: I think I've used a bounty only once to draw attention (don't quote me thouugh!). The other times have all been "omfg - that's fantastic - I can see the time you spent on this and because it's probably niche you'll never get upvotes on it - so have some internet points 'cos I think it's worth it"

Comment: If only this was on meta.SE, so I could give this answer a bounty...

Comment: @Servy Shouldn't this question be migrated to meta SE? It's not about something particular for Stack Overflow, is it?